# Binding django and angular 1

Tags: angularjs, django, rest, api

I have angular project that binding with django. 
Angular template has:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="document_received_date.html">
         <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.model">
</script>
```

Django has domain:

```
class Podgotovka(Activity):
  fields = [
     'document_recieved_date'
]
```

And model has field "document_recieved_date":

```
document_recieved_date = models.DateField(null=True, default=None)
```

If I edit input the client send http request to django.
I don't understand how client send request to django and how model write data to BD. What mechanism do it? Do you have some idea?